# Sum sql data where LOOP

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, sum

I have a table

```
 s_hostid |   s_name   |    s_size
----------+------------+--------------
        5 | 2014-01-09 |   1082705867
        5 | 2014-01-08 |   1082713736
        5 | 2014-01-04 |   1082686097
        5 | 2014-01-03 |   1082677818
        5 | 2014-01-06 |   1082701853
       10 | 2014-01-06 |      7536036
       10 | 2014-01-02 |      7536032
       10 | 2014-01-08 |      7536036
       10 | 2014-01-01 |      7536020
       10 | 2014-01-05 |      7536036
       10 | 2014-01-03 |      7536032
       10 | 2014-01-09 |      7536032
       50 | 2014-01-03 |  11416224886
       11 | 2014-01-01 |           39
       11 | 2014-01-06 |           39
       11 | 2014-01-07 |           39
       11 | 2014-01-09 |           39
       36 | 2014-01-02 |     22164534
```

How I can get sum values s_size field per value s_name?
I tried this

```
"SELECT s_name,(select sum(s_size) from storage where s_name = (select distinct s_name from storage)) from storage"
```

but have a error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Thanks for responses.

Comment: You mean *without* aggregating rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the `group by` clause is for - it breaks down a query to groups, and applies the aggregate function per each group.
In your case:

```
SELECT   s_name, SUM(s_size)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY s_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply aggregating would be too basic. [The manual answers that all too well.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP)

I assume you are looking for [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW), i.e. return every single row with a sum over all rows per group:

```
SELECT s_name, sum(s_size) OVER (PARTITION BY s_name) AS group_sum
FROM   tbl;
```

In this case, the well-known aggregate function `sum()` serves as window function after adding an `OVER` clause.

Comment: Thanks, but answer @Mureinik are 100% hit.